# Highlight a List component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder4.5

Sometimes the users forget to select from a Spark List component. Other funtionality depends on the selection from this list component.

I want programmatically make this list component flash red three times or any equivalent effect to catch the users attention. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Hope it's clearer now

Comment: @JanSander You should add a tag to indicate your `programming language version` (actionscript-2 or actionscript-3). What do you mean by list item? Is this a `List component`, a group of `several buttons`?

Comment: also there's so many different List components possible, mx, spark, Flash, ect. How can anyone guess which one it is?

Comment: Hope it's more understandable now

Comment: @JanSander I put an answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using a `Timer` and component colors, visibility, alpha, ...

Take this simple and working code using Spark List component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               width="280" height="191" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import org.osmf.events.TimeEvent
            import flash.events.MouseEvent

            private var timer:Timer
            private var color:Number
            private var border_color:Number
            private const color_1:Number = 0xff0000
            private const color_2:Number = 0x000000

            private function btn_colors_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {

                border_color = my_list.getStyle('borderColor')
                color = my_list.getStyle('color')

                my_list.setStyle('borderColor', color_1)
                my_list.setStyle('color', color_1)  

                timer = new Timer(300, 6)
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:TimerEvent):void{                   
                    my_list.setStyle('borderColor', my_list.getStyle('borderColor') == color_2 ? color_1 : color_2)
                    my_list.setStyle('color', my_list.getStyle('color') == color_2 ? color_1 : color_2)
                })
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function(e:TimerEvent):void{
                    my_list.setStyle('borderColor', border_color)
                    my_list.setStyle('color', color)
                })
                timer.start()               

            }

            protected function btn_visibility_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {

                timer = new Timer(200, 6)
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:TimerEvent):void{   
                    my_list.visible = ! my_list.visible
                })
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function(e:TimerEvent):void{
                    my_list.visible = true
                })
                timer.start()

            }

            protected function btn_alpha_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {

                timer = new Timer(200, 6)
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:TimerEvent):void{                   
                    my_list.alpha = my_list.alpha < 1 ? 1 : 0.3
                })
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function(e:TimerEvent):void{
                    my_list.alpha = 1
                })
                timer.start()

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:List id="my_list" x="16" y="18" width="148" height="150" borderColor="#666666" borderVisible="true" > 
        <s:dataProvider>
            <mx:ArrayCollection>
                <fx:String>line 01</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>line 02</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>line 03</fx:String> 
                <fx:String>line 04</fx:String>
                <fx:String>line 05</fx:String>
            </mx:ArrayCollection>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:List>
    <s:Button id="btn_colors" x="172" y="20" width="90" height="40" label="colors"
              click="btn_colors_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <s:Button id="btn_visibility" x="172" y="70" width="90" height="40" label="visibility"
              click="btn_visibility_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <s:Button id="btn_alpha" x="172" y="120" width="90" height="40" label="alpha"
              click="btn_alpha_clickHandler(event)"/>   

</s:Application>
```

The difference between the visibility example and alpha one is the opacity effect when using alpha.

You can also use an `Alert` control to alert the user if no item was selected, but because you only spoke about highlight effect I didn't include it in the example. You can use it like this :

```
import mx.controls.Alert

if(my_list.selectedIndex == -1){

    Alert.show('Please select an item from the list.', 'Select an item', mx.controls.Alert.OK)

}
```

Hope that helps you.